# Regex: Match exact numbers in large set

Tags: regex

Given a huge list (over a thousand entry of random numbers from 00001 to 60031) what's the best way to match every single numbers and only those numbers.

A sample of the list `00001,00002,00003,00004,00006,00010,00016,00030,00039,00177,00187,00219,00239,00240,00241,00242,00245,00248,00250,00258,00260,....,20065,20069,20070,...,27005,27007,28006,29000,29400,30100,......`

I know I could brute force it with a super long | statements and maybe a few tricks like range `0000[1-6]` but is there anything smarter? Yes I'm aware I could stick it in a script like python or like a database and match it accordingly but I have to do this in regex since the system is built that way.

What I have so far: `(0000[1-46])|0001[06]|0003[09]|001[78]7|002[136]9|0024[0-58]|....`

Comment: You already know it's a bad idea - and you have a mistake in your pattern (it will match `00005`).

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your problem at all, but why not `(\d+)`?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Just caught it thanks. Yes I know it's a bad idea, but I'm trying to find out if there's a way to make it a less bad idea...

Comment: @NicolasLeThierryd'Ennequin Because that matches every number, I need those exact numbers. I can't allow anything that isn't on that list. And since there's no pattern for that list I come to you guys/girls.

Comment: @MooingRawr OK, so regex is not a match for this (but nothing prevents your from replacing all the commas in your list by pipes, wrap in parens, and you get your pattern!).

Comment: @NicolasLeThierryd'Ennequin I already know that. But It's literally the only way I can do this. Trust me I don't want to do it but trust me when I say it's the only way. I know this is like trying to screw a screw with a jack hammer..... It's not pretty and it's not going to be fun but at the end of the day the screw will be in the wall, or rather what's left of it.

Comment: If it's the way you say, It's just to start building the regex. But that's impossible for anyone here, **since we don't have the complete list of numbers**! ;) So I think you already answered it yourself. I don't think there's shortcut.

Comment: @ClasG I wouldn't want anyone else to do this. It's suffering xD. I will do it myself I guess, with little range tricks and what not. Maybe I'll write a Python script to generate it for me...... That would be faster I guess.

Comment: By the way, a very useful resource to play and experiment with regex: http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get this app http://www.regexformat.com and from the tools menu, run
`Strings to Regex - Ternary tree`.

Drop your entire list (thousands) into the input box, select comma as delimiter
then generate.

It will create a regex that takes less than 5 steps to find any number
in the list and is *extremely fast*.

[Screenshot](http://www.regexformat.com/version_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg) and example strings [175,000 word Dictionary](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt)
The numbers are no more than the words you are searching for.

Regex from the sample you provided:

`(?<!\d)(?:00(?:0(?:0(?:1|2|3|4|6)|1(?:0|6)|3(?:0|9))|1(?:77|87)|2(?:19|39|4(?:0|1|2|5|8)|5(?:0|8)|60))|2(?:00(?:6(?:5|9)|70)|700(?:5|7)|8006|9(?:000|400))|30100)(?!\d)`

Expanded

```
 (?<! \d )
 (?:
      00
      (?:
           0
           (?:
                0
                (?: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 6 )
             |  1
                (?: 0 | 6 )
             |  3
                (?: 0 | 9 )
           )
        |  1
           (?: 77 | 87 )
        |  2
           (?:
                19
             |  39
             |  4
                (?: 0 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 8 )
             |  5
                (?: 0 | 8 )
             |  60
           )
      )
   |  2
      (?:
           00
           (?:
                6
                (?: 5 | 9 )
             |  70
           )
        |  700
           (?: 5 | 7 )
        |  8006
        |  9
           (?: 000 | 400 )
      )
   |  30100
 )
 (?! \d )
```

---

**edit:**

Adding a [Benchmark](http://www.regexformat.com/scrn7/s7_b4.jpg) sample to test performance.
Showing the results of using this regex with/without boundaries:
Note that almost all full trie regex generated using a ternary tree
will bench about the same, doesn't matter the content too much.

```
Regex1:   (?<!\d)(?:00(?:0(?:0(?:1|2|3|4|6)|1(?:0|6)|3(?:0|9))|1(?:77|87)|2(?:19|39|4(?:0|1|2|5|8)|5(?:0|8)|60))|2(?:00(?:6(?:5|9)|70)|700(?:5|7)|8006|9(?:000|400))|30100)(?!\d)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   30
Elapsed Time:    1.75 s,   1747.23 ms,   1747235 µs


Regex2:   (?:00(?:0(?:0(?:1|2|3|4|6)|1(?:0|6)|3(?:0|9))|1(?:77|87)|2(?:19|39|4(?:0|1|2|5|8)|5(?:0|8)|60))|2(?:00(?:6(?:5|9)|70)|700(?:5|7)|8006|9(?:000|400))|30100)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   30
Elapsed Time:    1.13 s,   1129.65 ms,   1129650 µs


(50,000 iter) * (30 matches/iter) = 1,500,000 matches
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Regex1 with boundary:  1,500,000 matches / 1.75 seconds  =   857,143 matches/second

Regex2 no boundary:    1,500,000 matches / 1.13 seconds  = 1,327,434 matches/second
```

Comment: Welp, I just finished my Python script to do what I needed, but now I can see I was wasting my time. Thanks mate. I will be saving this site for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
^(?:[0-5][0-9]{4}|600[0-2][0-9]|6003[01])(?<!00000)$
```

The first alternate in the non-capturing group catches most numbers by matching exactly 5 digits requiring the first digit to be 5 or smaller (note that this matches 00000).
The next two alternates deal with 60000-60031.
The second group is a negative lookbehind and is there to exclude 00000 which would otherwise match.

Depending on the technology you are using the negative lookbehind might not be an option. PHP and python I believe support it and Java definitely does ... JavaScript I think does not but perhaps you could check that one value with a secondary check?

Comment: Think you misunderstood the question (or I did). OP wan'ts to match exactly the numbers in his list, not 00000-60031.

Comment: @ClasG - Ah! Looking at the OP's attempt at the RegEx I fear you are right :-(. When he/she said the list was a sample I though they were listing sample numbers rather than a sample list (if you see what I mean). In that case I give up ;-).